# How to find which cron job is hogging CPU?

Tags: amazon-ec2, top

I am getting a spike in network utilisation on my ec2 micro instance at a specific time each day.

Using atop, I found that it is the daily cron that causes the problem:

```
PID RDDSK WRDSK WCANCL DSK CMD 1/5
722 3420K 4K 0K 98% cron
```

But I have 13 items in my daily cron, so how do I go about narrowing down which one is the problem?

(The problem might be logrotate, but although it runs daily I have set it to flush the logs weekly, so I don't expect it to cause a problem.)

Comment: Watch your cron logs and see what job is running.

Comment: Where are the cron logs?  I am only aware of syslog, which doesn't have anything helpful inside.  Syslog only tells me that cron started at a specific time, there's no detail about what scripts were running:     Jun  9 06:25:01 ip-00-000-00-000 CRON[10055]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))

Comment: The title of your question mentions CPU, but you've posted disk statistics. What are you actually after?

Comment: The problem is high read/write to disc, not CPU.  It is a problem because I am on EC2 free tier and read/write to disc (io) is charged extra.  So my goal is to minimise the read/write if possible but first I need to find out exactly what is doing the read/write.